# How to display the status automatically/Refresh the field automatically after a JOB execution In Oracle Apex

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1, oracle-apex-5

I am executing a job via oracle Apex by clicking a button which is taking some times. Currently i am displaying a field as "STARTED" when the job started, once the job finished its update as "FAIL/SUCCCES" in a table. Placed another button to check the value from table for the status.so need to keep on press the button to know the status.

Is there any possible to refresh the field automatically/wait till once the table value will update either  "FAIL" or "SUCCES".

Comment: You can certainly set a web page to refresh periodically https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-automatic-refresh-a-web-page-in-fixed-time/  That's likely the simplest approach but also the one that likely puts the largest load on the system.  That may be fine in a system with handfuls of users that would be launching jobs  where you can have relatively long refresh intervals.  There are more sophisticated approaches if you want to have better scalability and/or more immediate updates.

Comment: Thank you.. Actually i did same in a dashboard project ,But now the requirement is to refresh a field/page item not full page.

Answer (score 0):

better you can change the status like processing 
Use javascript and set the value like processing. 
once job completed automatically page will refresh and show the success message.